# Feature-rich Turtle editor

Tags: linux, open-source, text-editor, rdf

I want to edit [Turtle (RDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_%28syntax%29) files in the most convenient way possible.

Formal requirements: The solution must be **FLOSS** and a **local/offline client** that runs natively on **GNU/Linux**.

I don’t expect (but hope) to find a client that has all these features, so please also recommend editors which are only partial matches. There might also be really helpful features I can’t think of right now, so feel free to recommend editors that shine in other Turtle editing areas.

**Syntax highlighting.**
Maybe differentiating between URIs, prefixed names, and literals, but I’m open for anything (just as long there is *some* sensible coloring).

**Indentation.**
It should be possible to automatically indent the content in a sensible way, especially [predicate lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-turtle-20140225/#predicate-lists) and [object lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-turtle-20140225/#object-lists).

**Syntactic validation.**
Warn/highlight when there is a syntactical error, for example, as soon as a prefix is used which is not declared, or when a trailing dot is missing.

**(Simple) semantic validation.**
Warn/highlight when there is a semantic error, for example, when the local part of a prefixed name is not defined in the corresponding vocabulary. (*)

**Autocomplete.**
Offer autocomplete when declaring prefixes (e.g., when typing `@prefix foa`, the tool should offer to complete to `@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .`) and when using prefixed names (e.g., when typing `foaf:n`, the tool should offer to complete to `foaf:name`). (*)

**Construct URLs for prefixed names.**
Right-clicking on a prefixed name should offer a way to copy the full URL into the clipboard or open it in the default browser.

**Optimizations.**
Offer a way to search for possible optimizations, i.e., use of predicate/object lists, and execute them.

(*): For semantic validation and autocomplete, I’m fine with adding vocabularies (with all their terms) and the corresponding prefixes I like to use manually to the editor somehow. A RDF(S) import function for vocabularies would, of course, be even better.

Comment: Info: There is a free/libre [extension ("LinkedData")](https://github.com/blake-regalia/linked-data.syntaxes "Syntax highlighting definitions for various Linked Data languages") which offers Turtle syntax highlighting and prefix mapping auto-completion/validation (based on prefix.cc), but it’s currently only available for a proprietary editor (Sublime Text 3). Support for free/libre editors is planned, though.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I am pretty confident that nothing exists that meet all your requirements (but I would love to be proven wrong!).

Closest matches I am aware of are...:

- [Morla](http://morlardf.net/) - handles RDF/XML, not Turtle.
- [AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/wiki/RDF) - handles RDF/XML and SPARQL 1.0, not Turtle.

(full disclosure: I maintain Debian packaging of both projects above).

Personally I mostly use the built-in editor of [Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/) with a syntax highlighting plugin (written by me), [still waiting for upstream adoption](https://bugs.debian.org/956528).