# Semantically enriched document editor

Tags: text-editor, rdf

I am looking for a document editing tool that would be able to:

- load ontology RDF files
- match and suggest terms as they are typed from the RDF file and autocomplete them while keeping the attachment metadata
- allow to expand/compress sentences to the the core relation triplets (reader-friendly versus machine-friendly representation)
- store and load arbitrary data about different terms from a document database (alike MongoDB)

The idea is to decouple form from content in writing. For me, right now 95% of pain in writing papers comes from modifying context adjusting style while keeping track of references and needed data to support affirmations. I am looking for a tool that would allow me to decouple those concerns and manage the underlying structure more easily, the way it is done in the vast majority of IDEs currently (with rename variable / import variable / autocomplete from namespace / highlight syntax features).

The problem is much more present in the other way (reading), often because of the prevalence of the writer-defined abbreviation and relative references from the text that could be easily unfolded and put into context with right formatting, making reading and search for additional information easier.

The closest functionality for me is so far the TeX paragraph and bibliography management, but I am looking for something that goes beyond and is more costumizeable.

Comment: See also related question https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7568/79100