# RDF editor compatible with Mac OS

Tags: gratis, osx, text-editor, rdf

I need to manipulate [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) files created previously.

I need an RDF editor which also can interpret and represents RDF axiomatics in different serializations such as Turtle, RDF/XML etc. The tool that is able to create RDF list, Bag, Sequence or other RDF graph components.

I need a free tool. For example it can be a plugin for Eclipse or [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/).

Comment: See also related question https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7568/79100 - targeted linux but the tools mentioned might be available for MacOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Topbraid Composer](http://www.topquadrant.com/tools/modeling-topbraid-composer-standard-edition/) might be what you're after. It's a commercial product, but has a (feature-limited) free edition. It might be a bit "heavy" as its primary use is full-on OWL ontology modeling, but it can function as a basic RDF editor and has support for multiple syntaxes. It's written in Java (basically it's an Eclipse plugin) so it will run on Mac OS.